# Проверить скрыта ли клавиатура

Tags: java, android, клавиатура, kotlin

Основная задача, **убирать** с моей вьюшки **курсор**, ПРИ скрытии системной клавиатуры(по нажатию системной клавиши back).

Вот собственно вьюшка

```
 <com.som.android.features.common.widget.AutoCompleteInputView
            android:id="@+id/notesView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@color/black_light"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_20"
            app:fontType="regular"
            android:hint="@string/ui_data_attribute_notes"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textEmailAddress"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

И вот сам метод

```
private fun setupNotesView() {
    notesView?.setText(presenter.transaction.description)
}
```

Пробовал добавлять в метод setupNotesView следующий код `notesView?.clearFocus()` но увы он не срабатывает в этом участке кода.

Comment: Так Java или Kotlin?

Comment: @post_zeew изменил метку

Comment: тут изложены несколько неплохих примеров на эту тему: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android?page=1&tab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо [решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android?page=1&tab=active#tab-top) которое я Вам уже скидывал в комментарии, приходит лишь в голову следующий момент.

Так как играться с размерами экрана пожалуй на самая лучшая затея, поэтому осмелюсь предположить что там где Вы хотите убирать фокус с Вашей вьюшки, есть ещё какие то кликабельные вьюшки, в которые Вы и можете собственно прятать Ваш фокус, то есть, перед нажатием на какую то другую вьюшку в методе `onClick()` использовать Ваш метод `notesView?.clearFocus()` который при нажатии на любую из вьюшек будет убирать фокус, также не стоит забывать установить следующие параметры в Ваш layout, где все эти вьюшки находятся:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Надеюсь будет полезным.

Comment: Спасибо, да вы правы во фрагменте несколько вьюшек, и да в принципе получилось убрать фокус как изначально планировалось. Единственное думал что стоит лучше будет в зависимости от скрытия клавиатуры его использовать, но так уже тоже пойдёт.

Answer (score 0):

Задайте `id` родителю вашего вью, если это например, `LinearLayout`, затем реализуйте метод `onBackPressed` который будет слушателем кнопки `back`и в нем попробуйте реализовать:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
LinearLayout my_linear = (LinearLayout ) findViewById(R.id.my_linear );
    my_linear.setFocusable(true); // true/false соответственно
    my_linear.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); // true/false соответственно
 super.onBackPressed();
}
```

П.С. если вам нужно чтобы по открытию приложения клавиатура не высплывала, а фокус оставался, то в вашем файле `manifest` на уровне `activity` вашего `mainactivity` добавьте строку:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" // Клавиатура не будет всплывать по умолчанию.
```

Comment: Спасибо, пробовал нечто подобное, увы не получилось.